# Is Google Patents broken for others?

Tags: google-patents

It seems like Google patents has lost all of the page formatting in the last few days.  I disabled all extensions that may impact this and tried a couple different browsers.  The formatting of a specific patent page seems to be totally lost.  Is anyone else seeing this?
 [image: screenshot of unformatted google patents]

Comment: I have experienced the same problem here

Comment: This is more of a customer support issue for Google. We are not associated with that service.

Comment: We are associated with the Google patent display service in as much as patents.stackexchange.com links to Google when referencing patents.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I think this is an important issue and relevant to this site. Can we possibly have this question migrated to meta and re-opened?

Comment: I posted a question on meta a few months ago regarding the use of the [new Google Patents site vs. the old one](http://meta.patents.stackexchange.com/q/291/14417) on this site. This is potentially relevant to the formatting problem, which I've also been experiencing.

Comment: @vallismortis No, this is either a customer support issue or a technical issue with Google Patents. Their personnel are not part of this site  and we have absolutely no ability to effect changes or answer customer support issues regarding that service. Problems regarding that service should be asked in the support forums provided by Google. We have no direct affiliation with that service.

Comment: @RobertCartaino These sites are tied to each other in both directions. [Stack Exchange and Google partner with US government to battle bogus patents](http://www.theverge.com/2012/9/20/3362386/patents-prior-art-stack-exchange-ask-patents-google) "...the community site will be tied in with Google's Patent Search.. [and] ...Ask Patents ... will pull in relevant information from Google's archive of patent data." At some point in 2012, someone fostered a business relationship between StackExchange and Google. This relationship **needs** to be re-fostered.

Comment: @vallismortis The relationship stops with the inbound link. We have zero ability to effect change or troubleshoot problems with Google Patents, and the developers/administrators of that service do *not* monitor this site.

Comment: I had this problem too, but I think it was because I was using an old link. Seems to be working now after doing a search for Google Patents.